# Why doesn't my wav music file play in Qsound?

Tags: python, pyqt, media-player

This is my code :

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound
QSound("1.wav").play()
```

It doesn't play the music.
The file is 37 MB.

Comment: Does it raise any exception, or log anything, or just play nothing? Does the same `1.wav` file play in other software? Do you know what WAV format it's in? (For example, some tools can handle WAV files with MP3 compression, others can't.) Without _some_ kind of debugging information, there's really nothing anyone can do for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a QXXXAplication to create the necessary loop to reproduce the sound, on the other hand the correct thing is to create the object and then make `play()`:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    sound = QSound("1.wav")
    sound.play()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or if you just want to play and not modify any feature, use the static [`play()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html#play) method:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    QSound.play("1.wav")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Obs:

If you want to use it inside a GUI you must change `QCoreApplication` to `QApplication`. I'm also assuming that the .wav file is next to the .py file.